# Massive artifacts introduced when clipping beginning and end of (lossy) video in OpenShot

Tags: compression, video-editing

I'm new to video editing and am attempting to do a simple 'cut off the beginning and end and add a soundtrack' job in OpenShot.

The trouble I'm having is with horrendous artifacts in the exported video. The source material is H264-encoded, which I'm aware is a lossy format, but I wasn't expecting this behaviour when editing.

Some examples of the artifacts:

http://www.anselpol.me/i/

A comparison to show how vlcsnap-2016-06-18-18h34m40s443.png should look (albeit with a few artifacts itself):

http://www.anselpol.me/i/vlcsnap-2016-06-18-18h34m57s136.png

The artifacts were shown in OpenShot's preview, but I put that down to the computation needed to produce a complete image from the lossy source not being done for the preview process.

I've been reading up a bit more on I- and P-frames, and would have assumed that, during the rendering processs, an I-frame would be produced for *every* frame, thus avoiding these sorts of artifacts; it took long enough to export (hours) after all...

Could anyone shed some light on what's going on and/or what can be done about it?